# Trouble casting JMS Message as TextMessage

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jms, weblogic

I'm using a QueueBrowser to get and then loop through an enumeration of messages on a JMS queue. When I try to cast `msgs.nextElement()` as a TextMessage, IntelliJ IDEA tells me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jms.common.ObjectMessageImpl cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage
```

I'm very new to JMS and I'm not quite sure what `weblogic.jms.common.ObjectMessageImpl` is. Casting `msgs.nextElement()` to type Message seems to work fine. My code is below.

```
private void readQueueMessage() throws JMSException {
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Starting the subscriber");
    QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);
    Enumeration msgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
    //queueConnection.start();
    System.out.println("Queue started");
    if ( !msgs.hasMoreElements() ) { 
        System.out.println("No messages in queue");
    } else { 
        while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) { 
            System.out.println(">>> message count: " + ++counter);

            Message message = (Message)msgs.nextElement();
            System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getJMSMessageID() + "\tPriority: " + message.getJMSPriority() + "\tDeliveryMode: " + message.getJMSDeliveryMode());
            System.out.println("Timestamp: " + message.getJMSTimestamp() + "\tJMSDestination: " + message.getJMSDestination() + "\tReplyTo: " + message.getJMSReplyTo());
            System.out.println("Data: " + ((TextMessage)message).getText());

            if (counter >= 3) break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("stopping the queue");
    queueConnection.stop();
}
```

Comment: What is the class of the messages you're sending? it seems you're expecting a `TextMessage` but you're getting something else instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different types of messages in JMS. You are trying to read a `TextMessage` that basically contains a String, but the message you are reading is in fact an `ObjectMessage` which contains a Java object. You should check if the message is a text message using `instanceof TextMessage` and either ignore it if it is something else or throw an exception.

The class `weblogic.jms.common.ObjectMessageImpl` is simply WebLogic's implementation of ObjectMessage.